# AWS API Gateway working through CURL but not working through javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cross-domain, aws-api-gateway

Hi I am trying to hit a AWS API gateway it's working fine on CURL but not working from JS
Brocking for CROS policy.
But from AWS I already enabled CROS

```
$.ajax({
        url: ApiURL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(hash),
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        crossOrigin: false,
        headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
```

CURL method hit through AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url: stripTrailingSlash(BASE_URL) + '/contact/send',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        async: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
        },
```

My api gateway POST structure like this

My lambda response I did like this

```
const response = {
statusCode: statusCode,

 headers:{ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' },
body: JSON.stringify({
  message: responceMessage,
  input: event,
}),
};
callback(null, response);
```

Error I am getting in my browser

Comment: If you are using "proxy request integration" your lambda should handle the CORS requests. Enabling CORS in api gateway doesn't make sense in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in CURL because, CURL doesn't send OPTIONS request, but browser sends it whenever you are making a CORS request.

Response to the OPTIONS request is what browser uses to check whether you are allowed to call the API.

When you enable CORS in API Gateway, it will add the following headers

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
```

but if you enable Proxy Request Integration, API Gateway no longer modifies the response to add the headers. Hence, it won't work unless your lambda function adds these header by itself.

Comment: Tx for ur answer. but I already did that and my api gateway is not using proxy https://i.stack.imgur.com/puJf5.png

Comment: can you show what response you are getting in the browser for the OPTIONS and POST request?

Comment: Here is the error I am getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE2lA.png  and my request looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvVSC.png

Comment: you are not supposed to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST' in request. Remove it, it should work.